# Why would exchange rates follow a geometric brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, fx, modeling, currency, geometric-brownian

I'm reading Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance*.

On page 382, he begins talking about exchange rates:

> Finally, there is an exchange rate $Q(t)$, which gives units of domestic currency per unit of foreign currency. We assume this satisfies
>
> $$\mathrm{d}Q(t) = \gamma(t)Q(t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma_2(t)Q(t)\Big[\rho(t)\mathrm{d}W_1(u) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2(t)} \mathrm{d}W_2(t) \Big]\text{.}\tag{9.3.2} $$
>
> We define
>
> $$ W_3(t) = \int_0^t \rho(u) \mathrm{d}W_1(u) + \int_0^t \sqrt{1-\rho^2(t)} \mathrm{d}W_2(t)\text{.}\tag{9.3.3}$$
>
> By Lévy's Theorem, Theorem 4.6.4, $W_3(t)$ is a Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}$. We may rewrite (9.3.2) as
>
> $$\mathrm{d}Q(t) = \gamma(t)Q(t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma_2(t)Q(t) \mathrm{d}W_3(t)\text{,}\tag{9.3.4}$$
>
> from which we see that $Q(t)$ has volatility $\sigma_2(t)$.

Why would it make sense to model exchange rates as in (9.3.4)? Why would exchange rates be compounding? Wouldn't that result in every increasing (or decreasing) exchange rates?

If $\gamma(t)$ is chosen to prevent that, how are we meant to choose $\gamma(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that for long horizons this may be a strange model for FX dynamics. However, it doesn't always result in the FX rate tending to zero or infinity. For constant parameters the GBM has the well known solution.

$$Q(t)=Q(0)\exp\left((\gamma-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_{3}(t)\right)$$

For example if $$\gamma-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2>0$$

the rate tends to infinity almost surely. But if you set $\gamma-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2=0$ is does not tend to anything.

If we allow the coefficients to depend on $Q$, we can also set $\gamma(t)=0$ and $\sigma(t)=\sigma \frac{1}{Q(t)}$. This gives the zero mean arithmetic Brownian motion which also does not tend to anything:

$$\frac{dQ(t)}{Q(t)}=\sigma dW_3(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Whichever distribution is chosen, is must be able to cope with the Argentine peso, which has had multiple redenominations. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentine_peso): “After the various changes of currency and dropping of zeros, one peso convertible was equivalent to 10 trillion *pesos moneda nacional*.”

Whichever distribution is chosen, is must be able to cope with the US dollar, which has gone from being worth a handful of *pesos moneda nacional* to being worth about a quadrillion.